# Typescript not typecasting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to call a function from an object in my react state

```
//currentUser is of type User
this.state.currentUser.rankUp()
```

but it just gives an error `this.state.currentUser.rankUp is not a function`. If I create a new user object though it does let me call said function.Even if I try casting it as user: `var user:User = this.state.currentUser as User` then calling the function it gives the same error. I tried printing the type and even when casting it it returns as *object* not User

The only way I've managed to get it to work so far is `user.rankUp = (new User("a")).rankUp;` which feels like its incorrect even though it works.

**EDIT:**

User.rankUp is defined as:

```
rankUp(){
    this.rank +=1;
}
```

Comment: Should be this.state.currentUser.rankUp, () means its a function mate.

Comment: `as Thing` is a hint, not a conversion, it just tells TS you know what the type of the value will be (and, in this case, you were wrong). The solution you have is nearly correct, TypeScript won't convert a generic object (e.g. from JSON) to an instance without you newing one up. But you don't have to patch the one thing, try `user = new User(user.whatever);` instead.

Comment: Well, how is `rankUp` defined?

Comment: can you post the User Class

Comment: You need to post more code. My assumption now is that the this.state.currentUser is not what you think it is. Do a console.log(this.state.currentUser) and look at the prototype of the object. Are you sure it's a User? We need to see more of your code to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if I try casting it as user: var user:User = this.state.currentUser as User then calling the function it gives the same error.

TypeScript doesn't have type casting. It has type assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

So to answer your question:

> Typescript not typecasting

Because there is no type casting.